# React-How can I prevent going back to login page after login?

Tags: reactjs

I need to prevent my web page going back to the login page after login

I'm trying to make a web site using React and express.
I succeeded in preventing my website from going back to the login page by pressing the back button using history. push and life cycle methods, but I'm concerned that anyone can still access the login page by changing URL to 'http://localhost:3000/login' after login. using history.push('/') didn't solve the problem. I'd be grateful if anyone can provide any tips about this issue. All I could find about this issue on StackOverflow was about PHP, not React.

Comment: We can't help without seeing any code. can you please post some relevant example code so we can help you?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply assign a variable to local storage where you have saved your auth token. Then you have to put it conditionally in lifecycle method **componentDidMount** and then you have to redirect your desired route. check below code

```
componentDidMount() {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('authToken') // your saved token in localstorage
    if (user && user !== 'undefined') {            // check for not undefined
        this.props.history.push('/')               // now you can redirect your desired route
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using Redirect, this.props.history.push worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prevent an authenticated from accessing the login page because they're already authenticated. If that's the case, you can do the following in the Login component.

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.authenticated) {
    // redirect the user
  }
}
```

Make sure `authenticated` is passed as a `Boolean` prop to the component if you're using a state manager. If no state manager, you can also use a local function for the condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {  
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    useEffect(() => {
        let isAuth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        if(isAuth && isAuth !== null) {
            navigate("/");
        }
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **useEffect** hook to handle this problem.

Inside your login Page Component:

```
useEffect(() => {
   let isAuth = localStorage.getItem('authToken')
   if(isAuth & isAuth !== 'undefined') {
      props.history.push('/')
   }
}, [])
```

1. IsAuth is a variable which returns true or false depending upon the token stored in localStorage.
2. The empty array shows that useEffect will run only once the component is loaded. It means that once the user get logged in and tries to go to **'/login'** route. The useEffect will run immediately and check the value of isAuth, if the user is already logged in then isAuth will return true & it will redirect to the **'/'** which is the homepage you can say.
3. If isAuth returns false then the signin page will be rendered.

*Using this approach you can restrict user from visiting unauthenticated routes once he is authenticated.*

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using react-router:**

You will want to do this in your routing rather than inside of your login component so you won't see the login page "flicker".  This works in react-router ^5.2.0.

```js
import HomeComponent from './Home.js'
import LoginComponent from './Login.js' 

function App() {

...
  <Route path="/login" component={NotAuthenticated ? LoginComponent : HomeComponent} />
...

}
```